# how to create 3 finger and 4 finger click shortcut in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, shortcut-keys, touchpad

I searched a lot but I only got swipe and pinch gestures for 3 and 4 finger. Is there any way to create shortcuts for 3 and 4 finger clicks them too??

Answer (score 0):

Try fusuma-plugin-tap.
https://github.com/iberianpig/fusuma-plugin-tap

This plugin adds  3/ 4 finger tap and hold gestures.